# Call Django service worker method for another device

Tags: javascript, django, service-worker

I want to create a function `needsToBeCalled(a, b)` in serviceworker.js for Django that can be called from another device. What I need is when Django admin clicks a button, a function should be called but on every SELECTED device with service worker turned on.

serviceworker.js

```js
var staticCacheName = 'djangopwa-v1';

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/base_layout'
      ]);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  var requestUrl = new URL(event.request.url);
    if (requestUrl.origin === location.origin) {
      if ((requestUrl.pathname === '/')) {
        event.respondWith(caches.match('/base_layout'));
        return;
      }
    }
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
      })
    );
});

function needsToBeCalled(a, b) {
    console.log(a + b);
}
```

Service worker is working as it should, I just need a way to call this function from device 1 so it outputs something on devices 2, 3, 4...